# sort numeric string array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array like :

```
myarr[1] = "1",
myarr[2] = "1.233",
myarr[3] = "0",
myarr[4] = "2.5"
```

the values are actually strings but i want this array to be sorted numerically, also considering float values and maintaining index association.

Please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the normal [**`sort`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function. It takes a second parameter to tell how you want to sort it. Choose `SORT_NUMERIC`.

Example:

```
  sort($myarr, SORT_NUMERIC); 
  print_r($myarr);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1.233
    [3] => 2.5
)
```

**Update**: For maintaining key-value pairs, use [**`asort`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) (takes the same arguments), example output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1.233
    [4] => 2.5
)
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [natsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$myarr[1] = "1";
$myarr[2] = "1.233";
$myarr[3] = "0";
$myarr[4] = "2.5";

natsort($myarr);
print_r($myarr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [2] => 0 [0] => 1 [1] => 1.233 [3] => 2.5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the php [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function and in your callback function convert your strings to floats to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your strings to real numbers (floats) and sort them afterwards:

```
foreach ($yourArray as $key => $value) {
    $yourArray[$key] = floatval($value);
}

sort($yourArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
```