# php sort array values in ASC order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Below is my array, I want to sort it:

```
$arr = array('0-3 months', '9-12 months', '3-6 months', '6-9 months', '12-18 months', '18-24 months');
```

It responds with `sort` function like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-3 months
    [1] => 12-18 months
    [2] => 18-24 months
    [3] => 3-6 months
    [4] => 6-9 months
    [5] => 9-12 months
)
```

I want in below manner :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-3 months
    [1] => 3-6 months
    [2] => 6-9 months
    [3] => 9-12 months
    [4] => 12-18 months
    [5] => 18-24 months
)
```

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Can it only be `"x-y months"` or are there other values? What about overlap? Etc.

Comment: [Highly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075896/sort-numeric-string-array-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);`. `SORT_NUMERIC` treats elements as numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use natsort($arr); also

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SORT_NATURAL ?

```
sort($arr, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

source: [php sort manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$arr = array('0-3 months', '9-12 months', '3-6 months', '6-9 months', '12-18 months', '18-24 months');
foreach($arr as $v) {
 $e = explode('-', $v);
 $n1[] = $e[0];
 $n = explode(' ', $e[1]);
 $n2[] = $n[0];
}
sort($n1);
sort($n2);
for($i=0; $i<count($n1); $i++) {
  $newarr[] = $n1[$i].'-'.$n2[$i].' '.'months';
}
print_r($newarr);
```

output:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-3 months
    [1] => 3-6 months
    [2] => 6-9 months
    [3] => 9-12 months
    [4] => 12-18 months
    [5] => 18-24 months
)
```